# public sealed class SqlConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable

Tags: c#, .net, oop, multiple-inheritance, sqlconnection

Please help me to understand the following:

```
public sealed class SqlConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable {...}
```

In the above class I have two doubts

1. In C# multiple inheritance is not possible (we can achieve this through interface). But here DBconnection is not an Interface then How it is supporting Multiple Inheritance?
2. Iclonable is an Interface . It has a method called object Clone(). But in Sqlconnection Class that method is not implemented . How it is possible?

Please help me to understand this

Answer (score 5):

1. There is no multiple inheritence here. You can inherit from one class and implement multiple interfaces. Here, `DBConnection` is a class and `IClonable` is an `interface`
2. IClonable is declared as an [`Explicit Interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx), which means you cannot access it directly from the class instance but must explicitly cast to the interface type

**Example**

```
interface IDimensions 
{
     float Length();
     float Width();
}

class Box : IDimensions 
{
     float lengthInches;
     float widthInches;

     public Box(float length, float width) 
     {
        lengthInches = length;
        widthInches = width;
     }

     // Explicit interface member implementation: 
     float IDimensions.Length() 
     {
        return lengthInches;
     }

    // Explicit interface member implementation:
    float IDimensions.Width() 
    {
       return widthInches;      
    }

 public static void Main() 
 {
      // Declare a class instance "myBox":
      Box myBox = new Box(30.0f, 20.0f);

      // Declare an interface instance "myDimensions":
      IDimensions myDimensions = (IDimensions) myBox;

      // Print out the dimensions of the box:
      /* The following commented lines would produce   compilation 
       errors because they try to access an explicitly implemented
       interface member from a class instance:                   */

      //System.Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", myBox.Length());
    //System.Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", myBox.Width());

    /* Print out the dimensions of the box by calling the methods 
     from an instance of the interface:                         */
    System.Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", myDimensions.Length());
    System.Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", myDimensions.Width());
    }
 }
```

Comment: HI Thanks For helping me ... here you used IDimensions.Length()  right? but the Sqlconnection does not have any thing like that?

Comment: Are you declaring an interface inside a class? Im sorry I cant understand whats going on.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx        in this program Inside the sampleclass the paint method is implemented right? but in Sqlconnection class there is no implementtation for Clone() method...how?

Comment: Because it is an explicit interface implementation. You need to cast the object to interface type in order to see the method. `SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
        IControl ctrl = (IControl)sc;`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't multiple inheritance. As you rightly noticed, `DbConnection` is a class, and `ICloneable` is an interface. There is only one base class, `DbConnection`, so this is single inheritance.

As for the `Clone()` method, `SqlConnection` does implement it, but uses [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This hides the `Clone()` method until you treat your `SqlConnection` object as `ICloneable`. It's possible for a class to do this when class's author decides that the class should implement an interface, but the methods provided by that interface usually don't make sense to call on this specific class.

Comment: Thanks     we have to Implement Iconeable.Clone() method inside of Sqlconnection right? but there is no implementation like that in Sqlconnection Class ...How It is working?

Comment: @saran There is an implementation like that in `SqlConnection`, [see here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs#693).

Comment: Thanks It is available in this link..but it is not available when i search in Vs2012 Sqlconnection class. So I worried about this

Comment: @saran That's what both Yuval Itzchakov's answer and mine attempted to explain: if you've got a `SqlConnection con` variable, you cannot call `con.Clone()`, but you could call `((ICloneable)con).Clone()`. Not making `con.Clone()` the same as `((ICloneable)con).Clone()` is the point of explicit interface implementation.